# Call Javascript from Java - Android

Tags: java, javascript, android

I have app using android webview. I tried to call javascript from Java. I have the line below which I expect to display `hello world` but webview goes blank.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.write('hello world')");
```

Is my code correct or I missed something?

Displaying using `document.write` is for testing purposes only for calling JS function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change the string to "hello world" from "hello" :-)

I tried this and it is working

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.write('hello world')");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your answer but without success .. can you help me with my question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633793/call-javascript-function-from-android-activity-class

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this way

wview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    **index.html**
copy index.html in assests folder

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i used `document.write` to write `hello world` for testing purposes only. The requirement is to call JS function not just displaying `hello world`.

Comment: wat's ur requirement can u eloberate